# Render node with tabs in Drupal 7

Tags: nodes, routes, 7

If I set up a menu callback with this function:

```
function mymodule_menu_callback($nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid);

    return drupal_render(node_view($node));
}
```

Then when the node is rendered it is missing the 'View' and 'Edit' tabs that you get on the regular node/[nid] pages.

How can I modify my callback so that it renders the node with the tabs?

Comment: These tabs are menu items, too. Wouldn't it be simpler to just provide an aliases for your nodes, if you don't need to change anything in your callback? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Also, you realize you just omitted quite a lot of things [original node callback is doing](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_page_view/7), right?

Comment: It needs to be used in an ajax callback.